# Silverlight application privileges

Tags: development, security, client-object-model, silverlight

I have a silverlight application which uses the client object model to access the sharepoint server. 
When i run the app "out-of-browser" with elevated trust everything works great, but when i try it in the browser i get a SecurityException.

Is there any way to change this?

FYI: The server and the app run on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file in the root of your web application.

Read more about this here:
http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/8/15/security-error-using-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for-silverlight.aspx

Comment: thanks man. i thought. it doesn't need a clientaccesspolicy.xml on a local server. I guess sharepoint is special...

Comment: I could be wrong (been a while since I did Silverlight dev) but it might just be only for accessing the site locally.